# what is the greatest value of $|Z|$ for given equation...

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

[image]

How to solve this question?
Any ideas on how to start?

Comment: did you try LaTeX to write down the question?

Comment: @  GregVoit...its takes time in typing Latex...I have to search for commands...

Comment: LaTeX may be a bit time-consuming the first time you use it, but with some practice it is way faster than taking a picture, uploading it and posting it.

Comment: @Prasanta It's also a matter of making your question more readable to the answerers and showing a little effort. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: @Prasanta. See http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/ComplexNumberInequalities.shtml

Answer (score 1):

**hint 1**:: Use $\triangle$-inequality : $6 \geq |z| - \dfrac{2}{|z|}= x - \dfrac{2}{x}, x = |z|> 0$. can you solve for the $x$ ?

**hint 2**: its $c)$

Comment: @ BRIC-Fan....its coming $x^2 -6 x- 2 <= 0 $

Comment: @ BRIC-Fan...whose roots are 3+- root 11...

Comment: @BRIC-Fan...for greatest value its c...but if we have to find minimum then?

Comment: its $3 - \sqrt{11}$

Comment: @BRIC-Fan...okay...thanks....